# Error $injector:unpr Unknown provider: AngularFireAuthProvider

Tags: angularjs, firebase, ionic-framework

I'm rebuilding [this](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/eHPCs7s87O/angularjs-tutorial-learn-to-rapidly-build-real-time-web-apps-with-firebase) tutorial using the ionic framework, but I'm getting stuck early on with the firebase auth. When I built this tutorial app in just straight angular before, it worked, but now fitting it into ionic, I'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: angularFireAuthProvider <- angularFireAuth
```

The basic code layout is below:

#### app.js

```
'use strict';
var app = angular.module('wefeed',
              [ 'ionic'
              , 'wefeed.config'
              , 'firebase']);
```

#### config.js

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('wefeed.config', [])

app.config(
    function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
      $stateProvider
      .state('/', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: 'views/default.html' });

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
    })

  // establish authentication
  .run(['angularFireAuth', 'FBURL', '$rootScope',
      function(angularFireAuth, FBURL, $rootScope) {
        angularFireAuth.initialize(new Firebase(FBURL), {scope: $rootScope, name: 'auth', path: '/signin'});
        $rootScope.FBURL = FBURL;
      }])

  // your Firebase URL goes here
  // should look something like: https://blahblahblah.firebaseio.com
  .constant('FBURL', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx.firebaseIO.com');
```

#### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Todo</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">


    <script src="http://static.firebase.com/v0/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/v0/firebase-simple-login.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/firebase/angularFire.js"></script>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/config.js"></script>


<!-- Needed for Cordova/PhoneGap (will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>


  </head>
  <body ng-app="wefeed">
    <section class="container">
        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </section>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the tutorial is for an older version of angularFire. Try checking out the [quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/quickstart/angularjs.html) and [API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html).

Comment: We've published a blog post which will help with setup and some of the gotchas: https://www.firebase.com/blog/2014-07-25-ionic-simple-login.html